# latest SmartGWT 4.1 to solve IE 11 issues

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-platform, gwt-places, smartgwt-pro

I am using smartgwt 3.0 to create my project. However, with this smartgwt version, I'm facing UI issues in IE11. After investigation, I found that it was due to the outdated version of smartgwt.

I tried to use smartGWT 4.1 in `pom.xml` instead of smartgwt 3.0. But while using smartGwt 4.1, I am facing following issue :

> Failed to execute goal on project : Could not resolve dependencies for project : The following artifacts could not be resolved: 
>   com.smartgwt:smartgwt:jar:4.1
>   com.smartgwt:smartgwt-skins:jar:4.1
>   Failure to find com.smartgwt:smartgwt:jar:4.1 in http://www.smartclient.com/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of com.smartgwt has elapsed or updates are forced

Please let me know how can I solve the issue